# Show selected in multiple selection in PHP loop

Tags: php, multi-select

I am listing multiple categories.

```
<?php
  function listCategory($id = 0, $string = 0, $catID = 0){
  global $sib;
  $query = $sib -> prepare( "select * from categories where subCatID=? and isActive=? order by toSort asc" );
  $query -> execute( array($id, 1) );
  $view = $query -> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
  $xe = $querye -> rowCount();
  if ( $xe ) {
    foreach ($view as $row) {
      if ( $row["subCatID"] == 0 ) {
        echo '<optgroup label="' . $row["title"] . '">';
      } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $row["categoryID"] . '" >';
      }
      echo str_repeat( " - ", $string ) . $row["title"];

      listCategory( $row["categoryID"], $string + 1, $catID );

      if ( $row["subCatID"] == 0 ) {
        echo '</optgroup>';
      } else {
        echo '</option>';
      }
    }
  } else { return false; }
 }
listCategory( 0, 0, 0 );
?>
```

There is no problem with listing. Array contains category ID numbers.

```
$catIDs = array(4,7,18);
```

The categories whose id numbers are listed must be selected that are equal to their id number.
I've made a few attempts at this. I could not be successful.

I've made a few attempts at this. I could not be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
echo '<option value="' . $row["categoryID"] . '" >';
```

I edited this field

```
$catListA = array(4,7,18);
$selected = in_array($row["categoryID"],$catListA ) ? "selected" : "";
echo '<option value="' . $row["categoryID"] . '" '. $selected .'>';
```